# Oulook 2016 is displaying newsletter wrongly

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I updated Office to 2016 and suddenly I noticed that most newsletters are displayed wrong:

- This is how is displayed:

[image]

- This is how it should be displayed:

[image]

I disabled all Outlook add-ons with no results.

I'm on Windows 10 and having an Office 365 subscription. The problem was present also on Windows 8.1 (before upgrading to Win10).

Any ideas on what I should do next?

Comment: Can Outlook and use something which meets your needs.

Comment: @davidgo: outlook *meets* my needs, that's why I'm using it...